# How do you solve the Problem below?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $u,v,w\in \mathbb{Z}>0$ denote 3 relatively prime integers(Pairwise coprime). If $(mn)$ is irrational, can we find 2 non-zero coprime (non-square) integers $u,v$ such that:
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{mn}-n}{\sqrt{u}} $$ and $$
\dfrac{\sqrt{mn}-m}{\sqrt{v}} $$
are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $a,b$ are integers such that
$$
a = \dfrac{\sqrt{2mn}-n}{\sqrt{x}}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
b = \dfrac{\sqrt{2mn}-m}{\sqrt{y}}
$$
it follows that
$$
a \sqrt{x} + n = b \sqrt{y} + m
$$
Can you proceed from here?

---

Note that up to substituting $x$ and $y$ with $a^2x$ and $b^2y$, respectively, we may assume $a,b \in \{\pm 1\}$. Indeed, it isn't hard to prove that $\sqrt{2mn} \neq n$, so $a \neq 0$, and similarly for $b$. Working out my hint would then suggest $x = v$ and $y = w$, which is why I posted it.

---

After this I played a bit with $(u,v,w) = (2,3,5)$ and I don't think that this problem has a solution in general, though. The issue is this: according to Wolfram Alpha we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2 \, (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \, (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})} &\approx 4.79265 \\
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5} &\approx 3.65028
\end{align}
$$
(see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282*%28sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%283%29%29*%28sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%285%29%29%29) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%283%29)) and
$$
\alpha := \sqrt{2 \, (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \, (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})} - \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5}
\approx 1.14236
$$
The problem is that $1 = \sqrt{1} < \alpha < \sqrt{2} \approx 1.41421$, hence there is no integer $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{x} = \alpha$.

Comment: @ A.P. Good lead so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl I don't think that this problem is solvable: see my edit.